# Importing Product Open Data with BigDump

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import the `.sql` file from Open Product Data, the POD Database Dump. The site recommends to use BigDump, but when I try to run the php script from BigDump in my localhost, I'm getting this message:

`Stopped at the line 339.`
`At this place the current query includes more than 300 dump lines. That can happen if your dump file was created by some tool which doesn't place a semicolon followed by a linebreak at the end of each query, or if your dump contains extended inserts or very long procedure definitions. Please read the BigDump usage notes for more infos. Ask for our support services in order to handle dump files containing extended inserts.`

How can I fix this?

I already tried to open the `.sql` file, but it always stops working/crashs in my Mac